# How to avoid to extend the mapping on commiting an object

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Let's assume folowing class which I want to index:

```
private class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Added = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; protected set; } // Unimportant for search
}
```

The point is that I need just the `Id` and `LastName` property in the index. Using the fluent api everything works fine (just the specified properties will be mapped):

```
_client.Map<User>(m => m.
    Index("nest_test").
    Properties(p => p.String(s => s.Name(u => u.LastName))));
```

Now, when I index an object the mapping will be extended by the remaining properties. How can I avoid these behavior. (Also odd for me: `MapFromAttributes()` maps all of the properties, while not even one property is decorated?!).

This is a very little example but some of my domain objects stand in many-many-relations. I didn't try it but I don't think it's possible to map these objects when everything will be committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the answer in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1278:

This is due to the [dynamic mapping](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html) behavior of ES when it detects new fields.  You can turn this behavior off by setting `dynamic: false` or `ignore` in your mapping:

```
client.Map<Foo>(m => m
    .Dynamic(DynamicMappingOption.Ignore)
    ...
);

client.Map<Foo>(m => m
    .Dynamic(false)
    ...
);
```

Keep in mind though, the property will still be present in `_source`.

Alternatively, you can use the fluent ignore property API mentioned above, which will exclude the property entirely from the mapping and `_source` since doing so will cause it to not undergo serialization:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
    .MapPropertiesFor<Foo>(m => m
        .Ignore(v => v.Bar)
);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

or less ideal, just stick Json.NET's `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the properties you want to exclude.

Comment: Setting `dynamic: false` or `ignore` seems to have no effect (not in mapping nor in data). I am quite new to Lucene, maybe I need to look what `_source` in the index means. Anyway, the other solution and the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute are working. Thank you very much for your answer!